# Not able to show record in alert box

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

[image]

```
<apex:page>
 <script>
Result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from account limit 10");
records = Result.getArray("records");    
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
      var accRecord = records[i];
    alert(accRecord);
} 
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the [AJAX toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/) before you can use it. Additionally, sometimes the Session ID won't automatically import, so you need to specify it manually to make sure. Here's the minimum recommended changes to your code:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js" />
 <script>
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var Result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from account limit 10");
var records = Result.getArray("records");    
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
      var accRecord = records[i];
    alert(accRecord);
} 
</script>
</apex:page>
```